# Any REAL good Mac/iPhone combo IM applications out there?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, ios

I am looking for a combo of two IM applications, one for the **Mac** and the other for the **iPhone**. The main features I am looking for are as follows:

1. supports **MSN (Microsoft messenger)**
2. has **Push Notifications** on the iPhone
3. has a **unified session** (will explain below)
4. doesn't have stupid bugs (Trillian will not let you copy with ⌘C)
5. does not ask me to email someone that is invisible/offline (instead of messaging)

**Unified session** - I want the two apps (iOS and OSX) to share the same session, so when I leave the one and fire up the other, it should have my chats already there, exactly as I left them on the other device.

I have tried [Meebo](http://www.meebo.com/meebo/) and [Trillian](http://www.trillian.im/) thus far.

**Meebo** not being a Mac application did not feel right (not even when I applified it using [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com/)) but its unified session (in the cloud) was pretty good. The iOS app was good.

**Trillian** is a great application on both iOS and OSX but has some stupidities built in (like the *copy to clipboard* bug I mentioned earlier).

**What I'm actually looking for is something better than Trillian.**

PS: since I'm a developer, open-source is a plus

Comment: I'd guess there isn't any and I'm surprised Meebo is that good.

Comment: Skype does this, but 1) it's awful, 2) doesn't support MSN :(

Comment: Trillian is the only option, but the Mac app drives me crazy

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the unified session requirement - I've never seen that in any IM client.

However, I find Adium (http://adium.im/) is the best Mac IM application (and it's open source!).

As for the iPhone, have you considered IM+ ([http://www.shapeservices.com](http://www.shapeservices.com/en/products/details.php?product=im&platform=none))?  It works quite well for me.

Comment: Adium is good on its own and IM+ is good on its own. There is no inter-compatibility though. There is no way to do what Trillian does, which is to open a chat with the one (let's say iOS) and have it running on the other as well (OSX). It's the single most important feature of Trillian for me.

Answer (score 1):

You stated that you've looked at Meebo, and it has worked fairly well for me, though I've found [IMO.im](http://imo.im) to work better for unified sessions. Again it's not a Mac app on the desktop, but you can pop-out the session and get a semblance of a native application.

Comment: sounds nice and I will probably try it to see how it is performance-wise

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of [SkyChat](http://skych.at/)?

It's pretty awesome, and it works on both iPhone and Mac. I use it all the time!

Plus, as a developer, I know that the nuts and bolts in this open-source bad boy are up to scratch.

Comment: While self-promotion is acceptable per se (http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) it provides more value if you can show why/on which features your app is better than the alternatives.